# Unruly array not staying in containing div

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, css

On my website I have a JS function that  produces an array that can be of varying size depending on what input is given by the use

This is what I use to display the output array, perArrary, and some text.

```
document.getElementById("happyanswer").innerHTML= perArray + " are so happy, yes they are!!!";
```

The part in quotes itself always stays in the div . When it displays the array's elements it pushes to the right until it displays all elements.

I have the fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/m57KC/

Right now the only button that works is the happy numbers button. You can also ignore whatever issues there still are other than this one( there are many I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting an array directly to a string, with no `.join()`. By default, javascript joins the elements with just a comma, like `109,103,100,97,94,91,86,82,79,70,68,49,44,32,31,28,23,19,13,10,7,1 are so happy, yes they are!!!`. Commas don't trigger line-wrapping. If you join with a comma and space, instead, the line will wrap automatically:

```
document.getElementById("happyanswer").innerHTML= perArray.join(', ') + " are so happy, yes they are!!!";
```